# Is this relation in BCNF or 3NF?

Tags: database, database-normalization

I've got a DB scheme with the attributes (ABCD) and the following dependencies: A -> B, B -> C, C -> D, D -> A. I think it's only 3NF because there are transitive dependencies. Am i right?

Comment: There are no transitive dependencies. You want to work out the reasons on your own? (Start with the definition of *transitive dependency*.)

Comment: I tought A->C is transitive dependency, but C->A, so it isn't? Then   the scheme is BCNF?

Comment: What definition of *transitive dependency* are you using?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_dependency

I mean A->B, B->C but also B->A (B->C, C->D, D->A) so A->C is not a transitive dependency.

Comment: That definition is incorrect. Use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form#Definition_of_third_normal_form) instead.

Comment: I still can't figure it out :(. BTW every determinant is a key, so based on this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form) definition, the schene is BCNF?

Comment: I think it's in BCNF.